# 10 Clickbaits you can't resist

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

Write a program/function/script that takes a natural number i from 1 to 10 as input and outputs the URL of the Question with the i th hottest question on the Code Golf Portal

The ordering should be like in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot.
For example:
*input 1*
*output [https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127047/the-spain-license-plates-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127047/the-spain-license-plates-game_)*
(at the point of this edit)

There are no strong restrictions to the output, as long as the url can be reasonably retrieved. Valid outputs include strings, console printing etc.

It's Code Golf, so shortest code in Bytes wins.

### Notes

If your program automatically opens a browser with the webpage, it counts as valid output and is totally cool.

If your program does not retrieve the ranking from current information (i.e. hardcoding the links), it is not valid.

The contest ends with the end of June.

As questioned: The indexing must be 1 based, ie: the input 1 must return the the first site of the hottest questions.

#### Comment

I hope this question is not too clickbaity, as the stack exchange editor program was mocking me for the title. Originally I planned this challenge with Youtube trends, where it would haven been more fitting.

Comment: Re: Stack Exchange mocking you for the question title, it's just triggering on the word `you` specifically. The assumption made by the software is that if you're asking people what they specifically think about something, then the question is probably going to be closed as primarily opinion-based (as if the question were factually-based, it wouldn't matter who you asked). Of course, this simple heuristic has a lot of false positives.

Comment: I'm surprised the answers aren't using URL shorteners: [v.ht/b6QI](http://v.ht/b6QI)

Comment: @EngineerToast They're not usually allowed.

Comment: @Challenger5 [Indeed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10166/38183). I should probably re-read that list...

Comment: Can we output a JSON object containing the URL under the `link` key or must we output just the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PowerShell v5, 83 Bytes

```
(irm api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot`&site=codegolf).Items["$args"-1].Link
```

`irm` is short for `Invoke-RestMethod` which auto-parses the Json, makes life quite easy.

add four bytes (`saps` for `start-process`) for version which opens in browser.

```
saps(irm api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot`&site=codegolf).Items["$args"-1].Link
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python + [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), 128 bytes

```python
from requests import*
lambda n:get('http://api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf').json()['items'][n-1]['link']
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 125 bytes

```
b="http://codegolf.stackexchange.com";b<>"/q/"<>StringCases[Import[b<>"?tab=hot","Text"],"ns/"~~a:DigitCharacter..:>a][[3#]]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes no input and returns a string as output. Was going to use the XML feed, but it seems to follow a different ordering than on the page.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 221 bytes

```python
from urllib.request import*
import zlib, json
lambda n:json.loads(zlib.decompress(urlopen('http://api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf').read(),16+zlib.MAX_WBITS),encoding='utf-8')['items'][n-1]['link']
```

Based off of [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127082/43537) answer. Also, thanks to [Oluwafemi Sule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618741/667648) for helping me with an issue I had.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and mention that it is Python 3? Thanks! :-)

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Edited. Sorry about that.

Comment: `16+zlib.MAX_WBITS` can be `31`, the space between `zlib` and `json` in `import zlib, json` can be removed, and Python 3.9 lets you get rid of `,encoding='utf-8'`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7, 195 bytes

```python
from urllib import*
import zlib, json
lambda n:json.loads(zlib.decompress(urlopen('http://api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf').read(),16+zlib.MAX_WBITS))['items'][n-1]['link']
```

This is same answer by [Dair](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43537/dair), but using Python 2

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## [Stratos](https://github.com/okx-code/Stratos), 28 bytes

```
"-1"+
f"¹⁵s²&sort=hot"r"⁷s"@
```

Explanation:

```
"-1"+                    Decrement the input, and store it.
f"¹⁵s²&sort=hot"         Fetch the contents of the URL api.stackexchange.com/questions?site=codegolf&sort=hot.
                r"⁷s"    Get the array named "items"
                     @   Get the nth element, where n is retrieved from storage.
```

[Try it!](http://okx.sh/stratos/?code=%22-1%22%2B%0Af%22%C2%B9%E2%81%B5s%C2%B2%26sort%3Dhot%22r%22%E2%81%B7s%22%40&input=1)

Comment: I'm really questioning the validity of this, considering you made this language less than a month before posting this, and, *coincidentally*, there are one-byte builtins for `api.stackexchange.com/`, `question`, `?site=codegolf`, and `item`. Oh yeah, and a builtin for parsing JSON and getting an array from it in 3+ bytes.

Comment: More to the point, this returns a JSON object, not a URL like OP asked. Therefore, this is invalid.

Comment: Try re-reading the challenge, it is valid. This language was specifically designed to be able to look up the stackexchange API and this challenge just happened to be posted

Comment: Try re-reading my second comment, it is invalid.

Comment: Quoting the challenge: "There are no strong restrictions to the output, as long as the url can be reasonably retrieved. Valid outputs include strings, console printing etc." @Makonede

Comment: Yes, and this doesn't output a string of the URL or write it to a file or etc. It prints a JSON object which is not allowed.

Comment: As the URL can be reasonably be retrived from the JSON, as the challenge states, it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 106 bytes

Returns a Promise containing the JSON object for the desired question, which includes the link.

```js
n=>fetch`//api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf`.then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.items[--n])
```

- Sacrificed 2 bytes allowing for 1-indexing.

---

## Try it

```js
f=
n=>fetch`//api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf`.then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.items[--n])
oninput=_=>f(+i.value).then(console.log)
f(i.value=1).then(console.log)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number>
```

Comment: hm Im not sure at the moment how to handle 0 based indexing, but as the other answers appear to use 1 based indexing and it was specified that way, your answer is counted as 106 bytes (still current top score)

Comment: @Moartem: "*Im not sure at the moment how to handle 0 based indexing*" - Let me know when you've figured it out and I'll update my answer accordingly. I would suggest allowing for either 1-indexing or 0-indexing.

Comment: I will fix it to 1-indexing, so all have the same prequesites, please update your answer. Anyway thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Moartem: Answer updated. For future reference, unless there's good reason not too, the norm is to allow solutions to use their language's default indexing.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) + [`json`](https://hex.pm/packages/json), 85 bytes

```
<’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/…é?€¼=ƒËŠˆ&Šœ=…ß’.w„\"D„\\s‚‡’(EnÆá.€› (JSON.deƒË!"ÿ")["‚Õ"],ÿ)["ƒÚ"]’.E
```